# How do I instantiate AmazonS3Client via Spring?

Tags: java, spring, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, spring-boot

I am trying to create a Spring boot application where I am using Amazon RDS mysql database and S3 for storing customer image.
But as I am running my main class: I am always getting

```
Bean of type 'com.amazonaws.services.s3.AmazonS3Client' that could not be found
```

Below is my project hierarchy:

[image]

My question is the spring configuration file is in the right folder?
As I find instantiate dataSource via spring xml more easy. And on the internet I haven't found single example where Spring boot Application has used Spring xml file? All are using annotations?

```
<bean id="customerDAO" class="com.sap.JdbcCustomerDAO">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
    </bean>

 <bean id="dataSource" class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
        <property name="driverClassName" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" />
        <property name="url" value="jdbc:mysql://rdssample.xxxxxxp.us-west-2.rds.amazonaws.com:3306/customer" />
        <property name="username" value="rdssample" />
        <property name="password" value="rdssample" />
    </bean>
```

Is my spring config file at the correct path?

Please help me with the solution.

Comment: I can share the code in a zip file if anybody needs to test it. (Ofcourse after removing credentials for AWS )

Comment: You need to add the code and configuration to your question that is related to the S3Client. Are you trying to inject the bean into a class without defining the bean anywhere? Show the line of code that is actually causing the error.

Comment: Also how is this not an exact duplicate of your previous question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41497427/aws-s3-clinent-initialization-exception-bean-of-type-com-amazonaws-services-s It looks like you still haven't defined the S3Client bean anywhere, and are just asking the same question again instead of reading the answer provided to you in the previous question.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [AWS S3 Clinent initialization Exception : Bean of type 'com.amazonaws.services.s3.AmazonS3Client' that could not be found](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41497427/aws-s3-clinent-initialization-exception-bean-of-type-com-amazonaws-services-s)

Comment: Hi @Mark, I have been following the example on http://briansjavablog.blogspot.com/2016/05/spring-boot-angular-amazon-web-services.html Can you tell me where he has declaed AmazonS3Client in his example with the Bean tag?

Comment: You are missing `<aws-context:context-resource-loader/>` from the spring bean configuration file. From the page you linked: "The context-resource-loader on line 17 is required to access S3 storage. You'll remember that we injected an instance of AmazonS3Client into the FileArchiveService earlier. The context-resource-loader ensures that an instance of AmazonS3Client is available with the credentials supplied in context-credentials."

Comment: @Mark Thanks. Let me try after reading this line. I commented it intially  to try something new.